# Does infinite energy being spread evenly amongst infinite volume result in overheating?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics

I have an infinite black void. Due to the fact that it is infinite, no matter how much finite energy I dump into it, heat will not continue to accumulate as it is an infinite amount of volume and it will remain the same temperature. (In this case 14°C, don't ask me how this is possible.) However, what if there is an infinite amount of energy spread amongst the infinite volume?

Does my infinite black void continue heating up forever?

Comment: Would your energy density remain a constant?

Comment: $\infty / \infty$ is indeterminate. That is, it does not have a result. Trying to do it on a standards-compliant computer will produce [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (not-a-number). (And a "void" does not have a temperature. Temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the particles in a body. A void, being void, does not have constituent particles.) (More fun with infinities: you have a hotel with a countably infinite number of rooms, and all are occupied. Supposing a countably infinite number of new guests arrive, can you make room for them?)

Comment: @AlexP  I think that comment is probably an answer.

Comment: @StephenG: If you think so then write it as an answer. I will upvote it. I won't write an answer to a question I downvoted.

Comment: VTC: Not about worldbuilding, but please understand my reasons. This is a physics question at best, a mathematics question at worst - but no matter the words surrounding the question, I can't see a way to crowbar an infinite universe with infinite energy into the intrinsically limited context of the rules and systems of a fictional world. What's the point? Maybe I just need it explained to me - but what fictional world of your own design in which (pun intended) an infinite number of stories could be told would *depend* on the idea of an infinite universe with infinite energy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a pure enough mathematics and/or physics question that it is more appropriately directed there, for an explanation of why infinity divided by infinity is a question with no sensible single answer.

Comment: This sounds like a **Boyle's Law** situation: In a closed system, Pressure * Volume / Temperature remains constant. If Volume is fixed/held constant and you add energy, either the Pressure or the Temperature **MUST** adjust to compensate. You don't necessarily _need_ a Temperature change, but if you don't then Pressure will do Bad Things™. For this case, however, Volume is NOT held constant, and can expand similarly with the new energy. Therefore Temperature and Pressure don't necessarily need to see a big impact.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an infinite amount of energy to an infinite amount of matter - which is what you're doing; space does not have a temperature, only the matter inside it - does not have a defineable outcome. This is because "infinity" works in counterintuitive ways.

At the beginning of your scenario, all the mass in your infinite volume is at 14°C. That represents a certain amount of energy. For a finite amount of mass, you could determine exactly how much energy by using the specific heat of that material, and its mass and temperature, but in this case you don't have to. An infinite amount of mass requires an infinite amount of energy to be any temperature other than absolute zero.

However, this runs us into a dilemma, because if you had started your scenario with all your infinite mass at 0°C, it would *also* require an infinite amount of energy. And the difference between those two amounts of energy is **also infinite** - and more than that, *because these quantities are all infinite, they are all the same**.

The takeaway here is that infinity as a quantity (as opposed to divergence towards infinity) pretty much never shows up in physics because it very rapidly ceases to make any kind of sense whatsoever. Applying a finite amount of energy to a finite amount of mass has a solid, satisfying answer. But an infinite amount of energy and an infinite amount of mass is essentially unanswerable.

*Caveat: in set theory, it is possible to have infinities that are more infinite than other infinities. But those would make even less sense as physical quantities like energy than regular infinity does.

Comment: The difference between infinity and ‘tends to infinity’ is never as small as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Infinite is almost synonymous with constantly and ever increasing. In other words, both your volume is increasing without end and so is the amount of energy in it. The question is...which is increasing faster?

If the energy is increasing faster, the then the energy density in the universe will continue to increase and more energy accumulates.

If the volume is increasing faster, then the energy will be continually diluted and approach an energy density of zero.

If they are perfect balanced? I would think the universe would stay at whatever temperature it started out with. Which in your case is an arbitrary 14C.